# The Grid container on the right is the same height as the left one

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to work with Tailwind CSS grids and I am facing this issue where the container on the right the same height as the left one.
It should be as high as the content inside it.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/tAylernG5k

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex` to align the boxes and `h-full` to have the height of the blocks as per the content inside it.

Below is the corrected example shared by you

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="container mx-auto py-4">
  <div class="flex flezx-row gap-4 w-full">
    <div class="p-6 bg-red-300 rounded-xl h-full w-1/2">
      <p>Helllo</p>
      <p>Helllo</p>
      <p>Helllo</p>
      <p>Helllo</p>
      <p>Helllo</p>
      <p>Helllo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="p-6 bg-red-300 rounded-xl h-full w-1/2">
      <p>Helllo</p>
      <p>Helllo</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Ignore the warning